# manipulate a StringBuilder in a StringBuilder array in java

Tags: java, arrays, stringbuilder

So I have this piece of code:

```
StringBuilder[] a = new StringBuilder[5];
        Arrays.fill(a, new StringBuilder("asdfg"));
        a[0].deleteCharAt(0);
        for (StringBuilder s : a) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
```

and the output

```
sdfg
sdfg
sdfg
sdfg
sdfg
```

It seems that all element in the array is a reference to the same StringBuilder object, I guess it because of Arrays.fill(). Why does this happen and how can I fix this ?
p.s: I don't want to use a loop because fill() only behaves differently with StringBuilder[] and I want to understand why.

Comment: How do you mean "fill() only behaves differently with StringBuilder[]"? I'm sure it doesn't.

Comment: Can you indicate what is different with `StringBuilder`? Can you provide a sample with a *different class* that will yield a different result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure the reason for saying "`fill()` only behaves differently with `StringBuidler[]`" is because you've only tried with other *immutable* objects, and `StringBuilder` is not. Try

```
List<String> list[] = new List[5];
Arrays.fill(list, new ArrayList<String>());
list[0].add("hello");
for (List l : list) {
    System.out.println(l);
}
```

Immutable means that calling methods on an instance will not change it's state (like in `StringBuilder`'s case, the accumulated `String`, or in `List`'s, the contained entries.

Comment: Oh I didn't aware that `StringBuilder` is mutable and `String` (one of those that I've tried) is not. Sorry for wasting your time. Will be more thoughtful from now on.

Answer (score 5):

The behaviour you see is expected.

Quoting [the javadoc of `Arrays.fill()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object-):

> Assigns **the specified Object reference** to each element of the specified array of Objects.

Emphasis mine.

The reference here is `val` in the prototype (recall: `public static void fill(Object[] a, Object val)`, which is your `new StringBuilder("asdfg")`.

If you want to fill each element of the array with *different* elements, you need to cycle through the array indices and fill with a new object each time. For instance (using Java 8):

```
IntStream.range(O, a.length).foreach(index -> a[index] = new StringBuilder("asdfg"));
```

---

As a side note, you could have used an `IntStream` directly to build your array, although I'm not sure the code is really legible. **Stream API abuse warning!**

```
final StringBuilder[] a = IntStream.range(0, 5)
    .mapToObj(ignored -> new StringBuilder("asdfg"))
    .toArray(StringBuilder[]::new);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object)), `Arrays.fill`...

> Assigns the specified Object reference to each element of the specified array of Objects.

So yes, it is the same reference, and unfortunately you *will* need some form of iteration to assign a different `StringBuilder` to all elements.